# Woocommerce Product Variation Image change on Custom Loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I understand that Woocommerce looks for certain class names and so on for their JS to work. So my custom loop for the single page images won't work as intended.

Here is the loop

```
<?php $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID); ?>
<div class="imagewrapper" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>');"></div>

<?php
global $product;

$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
    echo "<div class='smallimages' style='background-image: url(". $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ) .");'></div>";
}
?>
```

This loop gets the products thumb and Gallery images and sets them as Background images using inline. But I can't get the main image to change to the product variation images. How would I go about doing that?

It would be fine if the product didn't have any variations. But it is needed in my instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what your asking, but maybe you could loop through the variations and echo out the attachments for each of those.

```
$variable_product = new WC_Product_Variable( $product->ID );
$product_variations = $variable_product->get_available_variations();

foreach ( $product_variations as $single_variation ) {
  $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
  foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
      echo "<div class='smallimages' style='background-image: url(". $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ) .");'></div>";
}
```